# Pendulum with Oscillating Fulcrum with Newton's Laws?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I was given an honors project to solve for the equations of motions of a pendulum with an oscillating fulcrum. I (somewhat) understand the procedure on how to solve it with lagrangian mechanics and the Euler-Lagrange equation, but I am stuck at a question.

How do we know this cannot be solved with Newtonian mechanics? I tried to look up the answer on Google and even tried to solve for it myself but I obtained an equation with theta, acceleration in the x and y direction so Im not sure what to make of it.

[image: Taken from google]

Does anyone know? Or are there any resources to understand the precise limitations of Newtonian mechanics?

I am a physics undergrad who just finished electromagnetism and linear algebra, thank you!

Comment: Would you mind providing an image of your physical experiment?

Comment: Yes, it would be something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_dXBthfkybQ/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Is this similar?    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558664/pendulum-with-oscillating-fulcrum-equations-of-motion

Comment: Newtonian mechanics is equivalent to Lagrangian mechanics, so whatever you can do with Lagrangian mechanics, you can do it with Newtonian too. AFAIK, it's often easier to obtain the equation of motion from Lagrangian because you dont need to do force analysis. Lagrangian formulation also provides you new perspectives on classical mechanics, that may or may not help with actually solving the EOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Newton's laws.

We have two masses $M$ and $m$ linked by a holonomic constraint

$$
p_c = (x + R\sin\theta,-R\cos\theta)'
$$

so according to Newton's laws

$$
\cases{
-k x + T\sin\theta = M\ddot x\\
T(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)'+ m g(0,-1)'=m\ddot p_c
}
$$

Here $T$ is the tension along the fulcrum. Eliminating $T$ we arrive to the movement equations

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 -k x-M \ddot x=m \left(R \ddot\theta \cos \theta-R \dot\theta^2 \sin \theta+\ddot x\right) \\ \cot \theta
   \left(k x+M \ddot x\right)-g m=m \left(R \ddot\theta \sin \theta+R \dot\theta^2 \cos \theta\right)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \ddot x&=&\frac{g m \cos\theta-k x \csc \theta+m R \dot\theta^2}{m \sin \theta+M \csc \theta} \\
 \ddot \theta&=&-\frac{\csc \theta \left(g (m+M)-k x \cot \theta+m R \dot\theta^2 \cos \theta\right)}{R\left(m+M \csc ^2\theta\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Follows a plot showing the mass $m$ path under the initial conditions: $R=1,m=1,M=10,k=1000,g=10,x(0)=0.2,\dot x(0)=0,\theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{2},\dot\theta(0)=0,t_{max}=10$.

[image]

Attached a MATHEMATICA script to build the shown plot.

```
Clear[M, x, theta, T, R, m, M]
solT = Solve[M x''[t] == - k x[t] + T Sin[theta[t]], T][[1]]
pe = {x[t] + R Sin[theta[t]], -R Cos[theta[t]]}
equsmov = Thread[T {-Sin[theta[t]], Cos[theta[t]]} + m g {0, -1} == m D[pe, t, t]] /. solT
parms = {R -> 1, m -> 1, M -> 10, k -> 1000, g -> 10};
tmax = 10;
equsmov0 = equsmov /. parms
cinits = {x[0] == 0.2, x'[0] == 0, theta[0] == Pi/2, theta'[0] == 0};
solx = NDSolve[Join[equsmov0, cinits], {x, theta}, {t, 0, tmax}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[pe /. parms /. solx], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

Comment: I see! So it is obtainable through Newtonian mechanics. One question is the fact that we have two equations of motion expected? Is this related to "general coordinates" utilized when trying to solve this system through Lagrangian mechanics? Is it not possible to narrow it down to one coordinate of motion?

Comment: The configuration space needs two coordinates. See the mass $m$ movement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Im sorry to bother you but could you give me a brief explanation or the program used to graph this function? Im not sure what you used to graph a two differential equation movement and I'd like to be able to visualize these motions.

Comment: Please. See the MATHEMATICA script attached at the bottom.

Comment: May I ask what the ' symbol implies in the holonomic constraint: pc = (x+Rsinθ,−Rcosθ)′ Im new to constraints and I would like to understand this pc variable. I understand you used it in the second equation to newtons law with m*pc so pc seems to indicate the position of the pendulum at a given time, why do you add the ' symbol then? Does that mean to take the derivative? What is the derivative with respect to and why would you take a derivative? 

Sorry if these questions come across as abrasive I am very thankful for your assistance and just want to understand further!

Comment: This symbol means transpose.